# How to know when focused element is refocused in voice over (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover

I want to do something when the focused voice-over element is being tapped again.

Function `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused()` will only get called when the element is focused for first time.

When we are again single tapping on the same focused element then this function won't get called. Can anybody suggest some solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody suggest some solution?

Here are some ideas on the fly to detect a single-tap on the same focused element:

- Create a variable `nbSelections` that will count the number of single-taps.
- Create a tap gesture recognizer on your element to increment the number of taps for instance:

  ```
  let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                   action: #selector(addTapCounter(info:)))
  tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
  self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  ```
- Add the trait that will allow to catch the simple tap directly on the element:

  ```
  override var accessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraits {
      get { return .allowsDirectInteraction }
      set {  }
  }
  ```
- Set `nbSelections = 0` when the element loses the focus:

  ```
  override open func accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus() { nbSelections = 0 }
  ```

Combining these ideas with the [UIAccessibilityFocus informal protocol](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#focus-an-element) could be a good line of research to reach your goal.

However, this technical solution assumes that the **single-tap is made directly on the element itself** *(-trait specific)* and not anywhere else *(I don't see how to catch this event the top off my head)*.